# Application that shows what functions are referenced by in C

Tags: c

I would really like to know if there are any methods or applications which can show me which functions are referencing which functions. So say I would like to see from where a function `change_state()` is called/referenced, I get something like:

```
                  /--app_init()<--main()
                  |
change_state() <--|
                  |
                  \--afile.c |<--trigger() 
                  /  line 100| 
                  |  line 156|
                  |
                  \--bfile.c|
                     line 26|<--|--button_event()<--process_event()
                     line 30|   |
                                \--move_event()
```

EDIT: I am using the Keil compiler in Windows 7.

Comment: Valgrind with kcachegrind will give you a lot of information: http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use gperf for that type of use.

It will show you a call graph, which is basically what you want, including performance mesurement.

First, assuming you're using gcc, compile with the option `-gp`.

Then, run your binary normally. It will output a `gmon.out` file. You can then use `gperf` to analyse that file, which contains the data you're requesting.

Comment: Shouldn't this be possible without compilation?